# Features are missing installing MS SQL SERVER 2016 with SQL Server R Services using web installer and command line

Tags: sql-server, command-line, installation, unattended-processing

I am trying to install MS SQL SERVER 2016 with SQL Server R Services using web installer and command line. 
 I am doing this based on this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt695943.aspx

Using same web installer, but not command line works perfectly. All desired features are there.
 Problem is that command line installation installs only SQLEngine and Replication features. 
 Logs investigation does not help much. It seems that proper files have not been downloaded and this is the reason why they are missing

My command line is:

```
SQLServer2016-SSEI-Expr.exe /ConfigurationFile=C:\temp\configuration.ini /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /MediaPath=C:\SQLSetup /ENU
```

And the configuration file content is

```
 [OPTIONS]
 Action=Install
 INSTANCENAME=MSSQL2016
 FEATURES=SQL,AdvancedAnalytics
 IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS
 SECURITYMODE=SQL
 SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="<username>"
 SAPWD="%password%"
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** Logs: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3028367/20161005_093914.zip

**Update 2:** I think I have found the reason for missing files
When I run SQLServer2016-SSEI-Expr.exe /? I get this out put:

```
Optional settings for basic install
==================================

D:\Downloads\SQLServer2016-SSEI-Expr.exe [/ConfigurationFile=C:\Configuration.ini] [/IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms] [/Med
iaPath=C:\SqlServer2016Setup] [/ENU]

ConfigurationFile              Specifies the ConfigurationFile to use.
IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms   Required to acknowledge acceptance of the license terms.
MediaPath                      Location where SQL Server setup media will be downloaded and extracted to.
ENU                            Use this parameter to install the English version of SQL Server on a localized operating
system.
```

**"Basic!"** I need **"custom"** It is available with the same installer if I use UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3192738 only basic installation is supported by web installer, at least at this point

Answer (score 0):

It seems your INI file asks SQLServer to install  only  few features like SQLEngine and analytics.

when you specify

```
FEATURES=SQL,Tools
```

[SQL will install](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dd239405(v=sql.110).aspx)..

> . The SQL feature will install the database engine, replication, and full-text. The Tools feature will install Management Tools, Books online, SQL Server Data Tools, and other shared components

when you specify

> FEATURES=SQLENGINE,REPLICATION,FULLTEXT,CONN,IS,BC,SDK,SSMS,ADV_SSMS,OCS

It will install all the above mentioned features

so you might be missing some features due to the way you are specifying

Comment: I'll try now, but https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx#Feature says "SQL: Installs the SQL Server Database Engine, Replication, Fulltext, and Data Quality Server"

Comment: can you post set up log as well